# How to reading parameter from .properties file to .xml file?

Tags: xml, properties-file

I have a config-sce.xml (Directory struct: ..\WEB\temp\Log\config-sce.xml)
and i have generic-path.properties (Directory Struct :\d:\project\config\generic-path.properties )

In this generic-path.properties 
PATH ="D:\project\resource\log"

I want to read that "PATH" property from the config-sce.xml file.